# Get one element from JS array, in any click

Tags: javascript

I have a constuctor function and a button. I want to get a name of one client in each click. but when I click one time, I get the name of all the clients in a sequence.

```js
function Client(Name, Feedback) {
  this.clientName = Name;
  this.clientFeedback = Feedback;
}
let clients = [
  new Client('Jo', 'hi'),
  new Client('Mark', 'bye'),
]
let btnRight = document.getElementById('btnRight');
btnRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let Client of clients) {


    console.log(`${Client.clientName} says ${Client.clientFeedback}!`)
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btnRight">button</button>
```

I'm absolute beginner, so any feedback will help me

Comment: Happy coding as you learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't loop in your event handler. Instead, keep track of where you are in the array outside the handler, for instance (see `***` comments):

```js
function Client(Name, Feedback){
    this.clientName = Name;
    this.clientFeedback = Feedback;
}
let clients = [
    new Client('Jo', 'Hi' ),
    new Client('Mark', 'Bye'),
];
let index = 0; // The next client to show
let btnRight = document.getElementById('btnRight');
btnRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // *** Get this client
    const client = clients[index];
    // *** Set up the next click (looping around back to the start if necessary)
    index = (index + 1) % clients.length;
    // *** Show result
    alert(`${client.clientName} says ${client.clientFeedback}!`)
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btnRight">button</button>
```

If you don't want to loop back to the beginning, keep a reference to the event handler and remove it when you run out of clients (or similar).

---

Some side notes:

- I suggest learning the rules for where semicolons go and then *consistently* including them (my preference) or leaving them out (relying on automatic semicolon insertion), but not mixing the two. :-) My guess is that you just left some out accidentally — and fair enough, you're new!
- I strongly, strongly recommend not putting the closing `}` at the end of the last statement in a block. It's hard to read (subjective) and hard to maintain (objective; you have to muck about if you need to add another statement). Use any of the standard styles, all of which put the closing `}` on its own line after the block.
- I suggest not using initially-capped variables (`client` in your `for (const Client of clients)`) for things other than constructor functions (and type names, in TypeScript), at least not in code you'll be working on with other people or asking for help with, etc. The overwhelming convention is to start a variable with a lower case letter when it's not referring to a constructor function.
- Finally, consistent indentation is useful for when you're reading code. I'm a strongly believer in four-space (or one tab) indentation, but two spaces is (sadly) very common. Whatever you choose, consistency is the key thing.

Comment: Nice tips. What I hate about four-space indentation is that you will get run out of your space pretty fast, especially in JSX

Comment: @bravemaster - For me that's a feature. :-) It means that I need to break things up more.

Comment: Could be. Have you written any blog or post related to your preference? I'd love to see that :)

Comment: @bravemaster - I haven't, but I've been thinking about it. (I have recently [started blogging again](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog) after having taken a long break while writing the book.) I've also heard an accessibility argument for using tabs (!) and letting each developer pick their preferred width. (Not all developers have good vision.) I did that for the first, oh, it had to be at least 10 years of my career and was happy with it. Primary problem is tools deciding to use a hardcoded width of eight spaces. for them. :-|

Comment: I have very poor eyesight but I'm perfectly fine with 2 space indentation. Thanks for sharing blog link, I will check them regularly. Looking forward to discussing indentation preference again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest removing the foreach inside the click function. And add a variable to track the count of clicks.

```
function Client(Name, Feedback){
    this.clientName = Name;
    this.clientFeedback = Feedback;
}
let clients = [
new Client('Jo', 'Hi' ),
new Client('Mark', 'Bye'),
]
let btnRight = document.getElementById('btnRight');
let clickIndex = 0;
btnRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
   alert(`${clients[clickIndex].clientName} says ${clients[clickIndex].clientFeedback}!`)
   clickIndex += 1;
   if(clickIndex > clients.length - 1)
     clickIndex = 0; 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Client(Name, Feedback) {
  this.clientName = Name;
  this.clientFeedback = Feedback;
}
let clients = [
  new Client('Jo', 'Hi'),
  new Client('Mark', 'Bye'),
]
let currentIndex=0
let btnRight = document.getElementById('btnRight');
btnRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert(`${clients[currentIndex].clientName} says ${clients[currentIndex].clientFeedback}!`)
  currentIndex++
  if(currentIndex >= clients.length){
     currentIndex=0;
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btnRight">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers are correct, yet here is another solution using javascript yield:

```js
function Client(Name, Feedback) {
  this.clientName = Name;
  this.clientFeedback = Feedback;
}
let clients = [
  new Client('Jo', 'Hi'),
  new Client('Mark', 'Bye'),
]
let btnRight = document.getElementById('btnRight');

function* yieldClient(index = 0) {
  while(true) {
    yield(clients[index]);
    index = (index + 1) % 2;
  }
}

const clientIterator = yieldClient();

btnRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const Client = clientIterator.next().value;
  console.log(`${Client.clientName} says ${Client.clientFeedback}!`)
})
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btnRight">button</button>
```